# Write and read class's object in a C++ binary file

Tags: c++, file, class

I had to make a program which writes and reads from a binary file the data stored in a class. The problem is that i made something wrong because it didn't write correctly the data in file so because of this it can't really read it as well.
I think that i didn't write it correctly when i tried to *write the object into the file* , but i don't know how to make it in another way.
Here is the Header file:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

class Agenda
{
protected:
    char* name = new char[25];
    char* city = new char[25];
    char* number = new char[25];
public:
    Agenda() {} //explicit empty constructor

    //setters
    void set_Name(char* n)
    {
        strcpy_s(name,25, n);
    }
    void set_City(char* c)
    {
        strcpy_s(city,25, c);
    }
    void set_Phone(char* pn)
    {
        strcpy_s(number,25, pn);
    }
    //getters
    char* get_Name()
    {
        return name;
    }
    char* get_City()
    {
        return city;
    }
    char* get_Phone()
    {
        return number;
    }
    ~Agenda() //destructor
    {
        delete[]name;
        delete[]city;
        delete[]number; //eliberating all the allocated memory
    }

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& output, Agenda ob);
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& input, Agenda ob);
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& output, Agenda ob) //overlading extraction 
{
    output << "Name: " << ob.name << ", city: " << ob.city << ", phone number: " << ob.number;
    return output;
}
istream& operator>>(istream& input, Agenda ob) //overloading insertion
{
    input >> ob.name >> ob.city >> ob.number;
    return input;
}
```

I overloaded the << and >> operators because that's how the task says, and i have to use them as well, but i didn't manage to use the overloaded extraction operator.

The source file is:

```
#include"Header.h"

int main() //read file name from KBD
{
    Agenda ob;
    string filename;
    cout << "Name of file:"; //entering the file's name from KBD
    cin >> filename;
    filename.append(".txt"); //giving the extension to the file's name

    ofstream wfile;
    cout << "Enter the data from agenda(name,city,phone nr): ";
    cin >> ob; //getting the data

    wfile.open(filename, ios::out|ios::binary); //open file to write in it
    if (!wfile)
    {
        cout << "File can't be opened!";
        exit(1);
    }
    else
        cout << "File created" << endl;
    wfile.write((char*)&ob, sizeof(ob)); //write the data from the object into file
    wfile.close(); //closing file

    ifstream rfile;
    rfile.open(filename, ios::in|ios::binary); //opening the file to read from it
    if (!rfile)
    {
        cout << "File can't be opened!";
        exit(1);
    }
    cout << "The file contains:";
    rfile.read((char*)&ob, sizeof(ob)); //reading the object's data from the file
    rfile.close(); //closing file

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: `istream& operator>>(istream& input, Agenda ob)` modifies a local copy. You need to take `Agenda& ob`

Comment: `wfile.write((char*)&ob, sizeof(ob));` does not write any meaningful data into the file. It also doesn't use your overloaded operators, so it is rather unclear what you are doing here

Comment: @UnholySheep i put the &-s and now the program didn't stop working, but it still doesn't write the data in the file, instead of it, it displays some weird characters

Comment: As I said, you are not using your overloaded operators. Why aren't you writing the object to file using `wfile << ob;`? What you are doing right now is writing out the byte representation of the object, which is clearly not what you should be doing

Comment: @UnholySheep ```wfile<<ob``` works, and the data is written in the file now, but i can't read from there and display it on the screen, i put ```rfile>>ob``` ,but it's not helping

Comment: My first comment explains the issue you have with your `operator>>`